# apt-get broken after upgrade from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: apt, upgrade, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have upgrade my 32-bit a few days ago to 64-bit without to much succes.

Since that happened my apt-get installer/updater is broken and can I not do updates anymore or install software.

I am working on Ubuntu due to that we received a computer at work I needed to work on for Web Development. Due to 32-bit was I not able to get certain software installed.

Just like any other good believing person did I thought upgrading was easy just as easy as I had done so many times on Windows but actually its not.

Due to the lack of experience with Linux am I completely stuck now and do I now know how to get this solved.

Help is more than welcome.

I followed this guide its a anser in on the post with 13 likes or ups. Edited by: mxdsp and aswered by: Asterix : [Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

The error I am getting:

```
    The dependencies of the following packages could not be installed:

apt-utils: Depends: apt (= 1.2.29ubuntu0.1) but it is not installed
            Depends: libc6 (> = 2.4) but 2.23-0ubuntu10 is installed
            Depends: libgcc1 (> = 1: 3.0) but 1: 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
            Depends: libstdc ++ 6 (> = 5.2) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1 ~ 16.04.11 is installed
code: Depends: libnss3 (> = 2: 3.26) but 2: 3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 is installed
       Depends: apt but it is not installed
       Depends: libgtk-3-0 (> = 3.10.0) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 has been installed
ubuntu-minimal: Depends: apt but it is not installed
update-notifier-common: PreDepends: apt (> = 1.1 ~) but it is not installed
                         Depends: python3: any but it is a virtual package
                         Depends: update-manager-core (> = 1: 16.04.6) but 1: 16.04.15 is installed
```

Comment: You mentioned 'upgrade' instead of a re-install.   The change to x86 (32-bit) to x86_64 (64-bit) requires re-install.  Did you re-install? or how did you 'upgrade' your system from x86 to x86_64 (ie. change architecture).

Comment: I actually did not re-install I have no idea at all how that works in Linux.

I just did found a page and followed the steps explained there and horribly screwed up.

Comment: ...and what did you do to upgrade from 32 to 64 bit?

Comment: I will put the error and link to the steps I followed in the post.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Well the [previous answer you apparently followed](https://askubuntu.com/a/894597/178692) says *"... took me the better part of a week. Including manually fixing 600+ broken packages in aptitude"* so you shouldn't be too surprised to find yourself in this situation

Comment: I would suggest you just re-install.  It can be done by Backup!, download install media (the release of Ubuntu you want in x86_64), verify download (md5sum) then write to install-media.  Boot it, verify it (just a safety step), then select 'install' & 'somethign else'.  Something else has the option to re-install using same partitions **without** format, allowing you to re-install over your existing system. The installer will take note of your install apps, erase system dirs & install, then re-add the apps you had (providing they're from Ubuntu repos) & ask you to reboot. It's pretty easy.

Comment: Was there some particualr reason you chose not to follow [this answer?](https://askubuntu.com/a/5020/225694)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to "upgrade" from a 32bit to a 64bit installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5018/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-from-a-32bit-to-a-64bit-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Use the command to initiate an interactive prompt of which packages you want to keep or get rid of to resolve the dependency problem:

```
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

This will go through a series of questions asking you which package to keep or remove. Note you don't have to select the first options given to you.

Comment: Thanks for the help as soon as a I run the comment I get the error: `sudo: aptitude: assignment not found`

Comment: I'm going to assume you are translating and `assignment not found` actually means `command not found` in which case you'll need to `apt install aptitude` first.

Comment: Same problem. Now I get: `apt: not found`

Comment: That's unfortunate, you've found yourself in a position where you have somehow removed the underlying package tools from your installation. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77957/where-can-i-download-the-apt-package-if-apt-get-is-missing) for how to remedy that.